# SHA-2(256) константы типа h0..h7 не 32 бита как указано в Википедии?

Tags: алгоритм, хеширование

Имеем константы

```
h0 := 0x6a09e667
h1 := 0xbb67ae85
h2 := 0x3c6ef372
h3 := 0xa54ff53a
h4 := 0x510e527f
h5 := 0x9b05688c
h6 := 0x1f83d9ab
h7 := 0x5be0cd19
```

Википедия сообщает, что эти значения по 32 бита, однако `h0=31; h2=30; h4=31; h6=29` бит.
Значит ли это, что дробные части квадратных корней для этих значений, просто сами по себе меньше 32 бит, или тут что то другое?

Comment: Под хранения данных констант в любом случае нужна будет 32-битная переменная (регистр). Просто старшие биты при хранении этих значений будут равны нулю.

Answer (score 2):

Вы путаете количество битов в единице хранения, грубо говоря, и количество битов в представлении числа, начиная с первого ненулевого :)

По вашей логике, для хранения нуля память не нужна вообще, а для хранения 1 - один бит?

Минимальная адресуемая порция - байт, т.е. 8 бит, так что для хранения 29-битового числа все равно нужно 32 бита в памяти: меньше не получится...

Comment: Добавлю что меньше бит хранит то получится, но тогда программа гораздо усложнится, всёравно операция может быть выполнена в рамках того что поддерживает процессор (регистры), и упакованую информацию прийдётся распаковывать с 29 бит в 32... и как итог - на перепаковку может быть потрачено гораздо больше ресурсов (распаковка = процессорное время) и человекочасов (для реализации) плюс увеличивается шанс допустить ошибку, поэтому так не делают.

Comment: Разумеется, для записи 29 бит не обойтись без минимально близкого 32 битного выделения памяти. Это я понимаю. Меня смутили формулировки википедий: (first 32 bits of the fractional parts of the square roots of the first 8 primes 2..19)/(первые 32 бита дробных частей квадратных корней первых восьми простых чисел [от 2 до 19]), однако, оказалось, что реально, 32 бита есть не у всех дробных частей, это и вызвало мой вопрос.

Comment: 32 бита есть у всех дробных частей. То что некоторые из них начинаются с нулевых бит ничего не меняет

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, в этом контексте, дробные части берутся как самостоятельные значения и отсутствие старших бит, эти новые, получающиеся значения меняет? Нет?

Comment: Когда биты хранятся максимально оптимально - это называют "упакованые биты". Они не могут быть использованы напрямую, перед использованием их нужно распаковать. В отдельных случаях это имеет смысл. Для оперативного использования информация должна быть распакована и одинаковой разрядности (почитать двоичное сложение например). Например все велечины 32-битные.